# Using "explode" to get at key value pairs

Tags: php, joomla

Consider the below data from a field in my database:

```
admin_language=
language=
editor=
helpsite=
timezone=0
page_title=Edit Your Details
show_page_title=1
```

I copied and pasted that data directly from phpMyAdmin -and so as far as I can tell the break for each KVP is a new line (e.g. `\n`). In fact, I found a forum where a person wrote a PHP script [that also echo's the idea that they are new line characters](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=656941). The answer by `najtrok` on May 12, 2011 at 12:18 PM.

However, the following script:

```
echo $newLine . "settings: $newSettings" . $newLine;

$temp = explode('\n', $newSettings);
foreach ($temp as $kvp) {
    list($key, $val) = explode('=', $kvp);
    echo "key: $key | val: $val" . $newLine;
}
```

produced the following output:

```
settings: admin_language= language= editor= helpsite= timezone= page_title=Edit Your Details show_page_title=1 
key: admin_language | val: language

settings: admin_language= language= editor= helpsite= timezone= 
key: admin_language | val: language

...
```

I can't understand why it's not exploding as I'd expect on a new line.

Comment: Eh, how about just [`parse_ini_string`](http://php.net/parse_ini_string) ?

Comment: @mario, absolutely fantastic. I'm very new to the PHP API, but I'll be honest, I do **love it** the more I learn about it. I've been building .NET applications for 13 years now, and I love it too, but I'm *really starting to love the PHP API!* That worked amazingly well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to wrap the newline in double quotes " instead of single quotes '. PHP treats the quotes differently, the single quote treats the string as is: \n where as the double quote evaluates the value inside the quote as the special character newline.

Comment: Unbelievable reveleation for me there friend. That worked like a charm. Thank you!